# SQL Geting json data value from row to another colum

Tags: sql, json, view, extract

I have coupule of columns in my table and one of them is a CLOB with json object.

I am working on data extraction mechanism from table and i was wondering if it is possible to create a new view with a new column containing certain value from that json (for example one column have rows with data like  ...,"request":{"status":"open",.....} and i want new column STATUS)

Do you have any ideas how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON_VALUE`.

```
SELECT 
     JSON_VALUE(jsonInfo,'$.request.status') status 
FROM
    ( VALUES('{"request":{"status":"open"}}') ) J(jsonInfo)
```

Result:

```
status
------------
open
```